# Porque meu código não exclui no banco de dados mysql/php?

Tags: php, html

*PRINCIPALADM.PHP*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A short description." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="put, keywords, here" />
    <title>universityhelp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estyle.css/userEstyle.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Meu universityhelp</h1>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="item" href="principaladm.php">Inicio</a> -
        <a class="item" href="create_catadm.php">Crie uma Postagem!</a>
        <a href="usuarioCad.php" target="_self" class="item">Novo Usu&aacute;rio</a></li>

        <div id="userbar">
        <div id="userbar"><a href="derruba_session.php" target="_self" title="Sair"><img src="img/sair.png" width="50" height="50"/></a></div>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div><!-- content -->
        <table border='1' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr>
<td><h5>POSTAGENS</h5></td>
<td><h5>TITULO</h5></b></td>
<td><h5>DISICIPLINA</h5></td>
<td><h5>AUTOR</h5></td>
<td><h5>ENTRE</h5></td>
<td><h5>EXCLUIR</h5></td>
</tr>

<?php
    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {

?>

            <tr><td><?=$linha['categoria_nome']?> </td><td> 
            <?=$linha['categoria_descrisao']?> </td><td >
            <?=$linha['categoria_disciplina']?> </td><td >
            <?=$linha['autor']?> </td><td >

           <a href='Postagemcomentario.php'><img src='img/entrar.png' title='entrar' style='vertical-align: middle; border-width: 0px;'></a>
           </td><td>

           <a href="deleta.php?id=<?= $linha['id'] ?>">
           <img src='img/Excluir.png' title='Excluir' width='30' style='vertical-align: middle; border-width: 30px;'></a>
           </td></tr>

<?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
    }
?>
</table>

</div><!-- wrapper -->

<div id="footer"><?php echo "Seja bem vindo ".$_SESSION['nome'] . "!";?></div>
</body>
</html>

<?php 

ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

*deleta.php*

```
<?php

$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); // Mapeando o caminho do banco de dados
if (!$conexao) // Verificando se existe conexão com o caminho mapeado
{
die('Erro ao conectar: ' . mysql_error()); // Caso o caminho esteja errado, o usuário ou a senha esteja errado, irá mostrar esta mensagem
}

mysql_select_db("tables", $conexao); // Selecionando o banco de dados

$id = $_GET['id']; // Recebendo o valor enviado pelo link

mysql_query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id='". $id ."'"); // A instrução delete irá apagar todos os dados da id recebida

mysql_close($conexao); // Fechando a conexão com o banco de dados

echo "Registro excluído com sucesso!";
?>
```

Comment: Coloque mysql_query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id='". $id ."'") or print_mysql_error(); pra ver o que retorna